# check if user exists statement works while email statement doesn't in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

There's this really weird problem I just encountered. User check statement works while email statement doesn't for some reason. Here is the code also `$con` is defined outside the two `if`s. I don't think that's the problem because user name check does work.

```
if(!empty($username)){
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username from users where username= :name");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rowcount = $stmt->rowCount($stmt);
    if($rowcount > 0){
        $errors[] = "name taken";
    }
    /* doesn't work for some reason */
    if(!empty($email)){
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email from users where email= :email");
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rowcount = $stmt->rowCount($stmt);
            if($rowcount > 0){
                $errors[] = "email is already taken";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the username `errors[]` does work while the email doesn't. I even tried echoing it out still no hope :(

Comment: You should move $email = $_POST['email']; outside if?

Comment: @chandresh_cool which if? filter_var?

Comment: Check for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `$email` before using it in `if` statement. Therefore, initialize it after `$username`, for example:

```
if(!empty($username)){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  ...
```

Comment: @theprogrammer Are your sure that your posted email passes validation? Also, try adding log messages to see what code runs and where it stops.

Comment: yeah i'm sure what do you mean by adding log messages? can you explain how do i add that? ( the code)

Comment: just add `echo "email is not empty";`, `echo "filter validation succesful";` and etc.

Comment: thanks that was really useful it seems to stop at the second if when i try to validate and !empty the email. which is weird

Comment: Then either you don't receive $_POST[email] or it is invalid - check it.